# Is it possible to run a webview automation script using appium in browser stack device

Tags: webview, automation, appium, payment-gateway, browserstack

I need to automate an application which consists of payment gateway which asks for card number,cvv etc..using appium.As per the requirement i need to run the script in real device and in browser stack devices.
My script is running perfectly in real devices,but not in browser stack.Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing a few tests after switching to Webview context and then performing the subsequent actions?

You can read more on the [Automating Hybrid Apps](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) in the official documentation of Appium.

You can try changing the 'browserstack.appium_version' capability in your test scripts to the different [Appium versions](https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities#mobile-capabilities) supported on BrowserStack.